# Directive not compiling sometimes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `window.onload` inside my directive, and because of this sometimes my directive compiles and sometimes not.

Actually I need some external libraries for UMD, and that object is used in `window.onload(native JS)`.

Its understood that the main cause is `windows.onload`, but do somebody know conceptually where the actual problem is? do I need to change `window.onload` or need to change app architecture? or what I can do to prevent this behavior? Its your call :)

Thanks

Comment: [How to use or inject thirdparty lib in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18347194/1176601) might help

Comment: actually wanted to know if delaying due to window.onload is a reason then how to overcome that.